# Problems with Codeigniter update_batch

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter-3, crud

I have a view file in which I generate some input fields based on a database get operation. I am trying to get marks for students that appeared for a test. These students are populated dynamically and here is the code for the view file.

**View**

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('info')) { ?>
            <div class="alert alert-info">
                <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('info'); ?>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php echo form_open('dashboard/insert_marks'); ?>
            <?php foreach($entries as $ent) { ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label><?php echo ($ent->id); ?></label>
                        <input type="text" name="id" class="form-control" placeholder="N/A" disabled>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label><?php echo ($ent->student_name); ?></label>
                        <input type="text" name="marks" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <button type="submit" name="save" value="Save Data" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**Controller**

In the controller I am trying to create an array of arrays so that I can insert all these values at a time with the help of Codeigniter update_batch function. I have pasted the code of Controller file below.

```
public function insert_marks() {
    $this->load->model('Marks_Model');
    if($this->input->post('save'))
    {
        $idlist[] = $this->input->post('id');
        $marklist[] = $this->input->post('marks');

        $marks_data = array(array());

        for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($idlist); $x++){
            $marks_data[] = array(
                'id' => $idlist[$x],
                'marks' => $marklist[$x]
            );
        }

        $this->Marks_Model->update_marks($marks_data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('info','Marks Updated Successfully');
        redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'refresh');
    }
```

**Model**
In the model I have made the call to update_batch to insert all dtaa from the array. This is the first time I have used update_batch.

```
public function update_marks($marks_data) {
    $this->db->update_batch('marks',$marks_data,'id'); 
}
```

**Error**

I have an error "One or more rows submitted for batch updating is missing the specified index."

I dont know what went wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inputs will already be arrays, so use `$idlist =` instead of `$idlist[] =`, same for `$marklist`.  This may be the reason for the "missing the specified index" error.

`$marks_data` should be just an array, not an array inside an array. This might also be the reason for the error.

The creation of `$marks_data` is slightly easier to write (and read, IMO) using a `foreach` loop.

Put that all together and you get this.

```
public function insert_marks()
{
    $this->load->model('Marks_Model');

    if($this->input->post('save'))
    {
        $idlist = $this->input->post('id');
        $marklist = $this->input->post('marks');

        $marks_data = array();

        foreach($idlist as $key => $id)
        {
            // we are filling an array with arrays here
            $marks_data[] = array('id' => $id, 'marks' => $marklist[$key]);
        }

        $this->Marks_Model->update_marks($marks_data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('info', 'Marks Updated Successfully');
        redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'refresh');
    }
}
```

One more change is needed. The view code `foreach($entries as $ent)` tells us there might be more than one pair of `id`/`marks` inputs. This means that the input names must be arrays so make that change as shown next.

```
// Change this
<input type="text" name="id" ...
// to this
<input type="text" name="id[]" ...
```

Do the same for `<input type="text" name="marks"` changing it to `<input type="text" name="marks[]"` .  This change assures that `$idlist` and `$marklist` will be arrays which is necessasary if the `foreach` is to work.

Making sure it will "work" requires a bit more code for this method. Checks should be made to confirm that values are provided. Then too, those values should be validated and sanitized (NEVER trust user input) before inserting into the database.

Comment: I tried this. got an error " Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: same error even after updating. I also tried for loop with it.Doesn't give an error  But nothing gets written in database. I might have to change my strategy about entering marks for each student. one by one I suppose.

Comment: What does `$marks_data` look like? Try a `var_dump($marks_data); exit;` before sending it to the model.

Comment: I did that and idlist[0] had nothing in it. Somehow we don't have anything in this array. Nothing.

Comment: Marklist has all the data just not the id

Comment: Ok. I see the problem now. Input field id has no value.

Comment: I just noticed you have that field disabled. Disabled inputs are not submitted with the form. I suggest using a hidden field instead. If you need to see the id value just do it as text

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It is working fine now.